# Como enlazar el estilo de un modal jQuery en su ultima versión

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente problema al vincular jQuery UI.

hace un momento funcionaba perfecto, ahora sale en la esquina inferior izquierda, no se que ha pasado, la version de jQuery es la 1.12.

este es el codigo:

aqui muestro el codigo html:

```js
// codigo del modal-form
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frmPaciente').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    heigth: 310,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Crear",
        click: insertarPaciente()
      },
      {
        text: "Cerrar",
        click: cancelar()
      }
    ]
  });
});

function mostrarFormulario() {
  documento = "" + $("#asignarDocumento").val();
  $("#pacDocumento").attr("value", documento);
  $("#frmPaciente").dialog("open");

}

function insertarPaciente() {
  $(this).dialog("close");
  queryString = $("#agregarPaciente").serialize();
  url = "index.php?accion=ingresarPaciente&" + queryString;
  $("#paciente").load(url);
}

function cancelar() {
  $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Sistema Gestion Odontologica</title>
  <link href="Vista/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/js/script.js"></script>
  <!--Archivos Necesarios para el dialog-->
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--fin de archivos necesarios para el dialog-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <div id="encabezado">
      <img src="Vista/imagenes/odontologia.png" width="100%" height="150px">
    </div>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="activa"><a href="index.php?accion=asignar">Asignar Cita</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?accion=consultar">Consultar Cita</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?accion=cancelar">Cancelar Cita</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="contenido">
      <h2 style="width:100%">Asignar Cita</h2>
      <form id="frmAsignar" method="POST" action="index.php?accion=guardarCita">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Documento del Paciente</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="asignarDocumento" id="asignarDocumento"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <input type="button" name="asignarConsultar" value="Consultar" id="asignarConsultar" onclick="consultarPaciente()">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <div id="paciente"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Medico: </td>
            <td>
              <select id="medico" name="medico">
                <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione el Medico---</option>
                <option value="12345">12345 Camilo Robledo</option>
                <option value="67890">67890 Esteban Salgado</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Fecha: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hora: </td>
            <td>
              <select id="hora" name="hora">
                <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione la hora---</option>
                <option>8:00:00</option>
                <option>8:20:00</option>
                <option>8:40:00</option>
                <option>9:00:00</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Consultorio: </td>
            <td>
              <select id="consultorio" name="consultorio">
                <option value="-1" selected="selected">---Seleccione el Consultorio---</option>
                <option value="1">1 Consultas1</option>
                <option value="2">2 Tratamientos2</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <input type="submit" name="asignarEnviar" value="Enviar" id="asignarEnviar">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ventana modal-->
  <div id="frmPaciente" title="Agregar Nuevo Paciente">
    <form id="agregarPaciente">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Documento</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="pacDocumento" id="pacDocumento" readonly="readonly"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Nombres</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="pacNombres" id="pacNombres"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Apellidos</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="pacApellidos" id="pacApellidos"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fecha de Nacimiento</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="pacNacimiento" id="pacNacimiento"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sexo</td>
          <td>
            <select id="pacSexo" name="pacSexo">
              <option value="-1" selected="selected">
                <---Seleccione Sexo--->
              </option>
              <option>m</option>
              <option>f</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

esta es la captura del modal donde esta saliedo, los botones ya no aparecen.

[image: ejecucion del sistema]

no se si tengo mal enlazado el css de jQuery, pero como decia antes estaba funcionando.

gracias por su ayuda, estoy empezando en esto.

Answer (score 0):

Y encontre la forma de solucionarlo, no se porque no enlazaba bien las direcciones en la carpeta jQuery, obtuve las direcciones desde el almacenamiento en un servidor de jQuery, es decir encontre los archivos en la nube.

esta era mi antiguo html:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Sistema Gestion Odontologica</title>
  <link href="Vista/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/js/script.js"></script>
  <!--Archivos Necesarios para el dialog-->
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--fin de archivos necesarios para el dialog-->
</head>
```

ahora actualize las direcciones por este:

```html
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>Sistema Gestion Odontologica</title>
        <link href="Vista/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/js/script.js"></script>
        <!--Archivos Necesarios para el dialog-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--fin de archivos necesarios para el dialog-->
    </head>
```

Creo que es mejor obtener las direcciones desde el servidor propio de jQuery por compatibilidad.